# X-ray bombardment of CaCl2 and its resultant chemical changes

Tags: ionic-compounds, ionization-energy, chemical-engineering, nuclear-chemistry

If one were to take $\pu{1 mol}$ of pure liquid Calcium Chloride (at $\pu{600 ^\circ C}$) and bombard it with $\pu{7.65 \times 10^{14} Ci}$ ($\pu{2.83 \times 10^25 particles}$) of x-rays ($\pu{75 keV}$), how the calcium chloride become chemically altered in anyway? Would the radiation cause the calcium and/or chloride ions to further ionize into a form that would not bond with the other ions?

I ask this because my purpose requires that the liquid $\ce{CaCl2}$ (not aqueous) would be able to keep the calcium and chlorine from precipitating out of the liquid.

Comment: What's Cu?$\mathstrut$

Comment: @ivan neretin Cu is the symbol for Curies in this case. 1 Curie is equal to around 3.7 * 10^10 x-rays per second.

Comment: I thought Curie is Ci, but what do I know. Whatever. Well, then in effect your sample is sitting near the center of a decent nuclear explosion, so its temperature, phase state, shape, chemical composition, and pretty much everything else about it are rather irrelevant. A rapidly expanding cloud of hot plasma does not remember what it was before.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So effectively it will just become plasma?

Comment: Yes, many times over.

Comment: @JonCuster Greetings, I thought that the energy o the X-rays would have been 340 billion joules, as there would be 7.62*10^14 Curies of x-rays, each with an energy of 75 keV. That would total about 2.12 * 10^30 eV, which is 340 billion joules, rather than 6 joules. Was there an error in how I quantified this?

Comment: Ahhh, totally screwed up - I'm used to doses in flux... Sigh...